# jQuery and AJAX - Object dynamic added with Ajax won't work with jQuery functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So I have a MVC code that generates something like this

```
<div class="photoset">
  <img />
  <img />
</div>

<div class="photoset">
  <img />
  <img />
  <img />
</div>
```

And I'm trying to make a jQuery to infinite scroll and as the user is scrolling, it generates more photosets.

I was somewhat successful in doing that but, after I generate more photosets with my infinite scroll, the newly added code won't work with my previous jQuery plugin to navigate between images.

Here is the jQuery code to navigate:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.photoset').each(function () {
        $(this).data('counter', 0);
        $items = $(this).find('img')
        $(this).data('numItems', $items.length);
        $(this).closest('.row').prev('.row').find('.nav-informer').text($(this).data('counter') + 1 + " de " + $(this).data('numItems'));

        if (($items.eq(0).width() / $items.eq(0).height()) < 1) {
            $(this).css({
                width: "445",
                height: "667",
                margin: "auto"
            });
        }
    });

    var showCurrent = function (photoset) {
        $items = photoset.find('img');
        var counter = photoset.data('counter');
        var numItems = $items.length;
        var itemToShow = Math.abs(counter % numItems);
        $items.fadeOut(1000);
        $items.eq(itemToShow).fadeIn(1000);
    };

    /* ---------------------------------------------- /*
     * Prev
     /* ---------------------------------------------- */
    $('.prev').on('click', function () {
        var photoset = $(this).closest('.row').prev('.row').find('.photoset');
        photoset.data('counter', photoset.data('counter') - 1);
        if (photoset.data('counter') < 0)
            photoset.data('counter', photoset.data('numItems') - 1);
        photoset.closest('.row').prev('.row').find('.nav-informer').text(photoset.data('counter') + 1 + " de " + photoset.data('numItems'));
        showCurrent(photoset);
    });

    /* ---------------------------------------------- /*
     * Next
     /* ---------------------------------------------- */
    $('.next').on('click', function () {
        var photoset = $(this).closest('.row').prev('.row').find('.photoset');
        photoset.data('counter', photoset.data('counter') + 1);
        if (photoset.data('counter') > photoset.data('numItems') - 1)
            photoset.data('counter', 0);
        photoset.closest('.row').prev('.row').find('.nav-informer').text(photoset.data('counter') + 1 + " de " + photoset.data('numItems'));
        showCurrent(photoset);
    });
});
```

And the Ajax function to call for more photosets, passing the page number:

**Ajax**

```
var page = 0,
inCallback = false,
hasReachedEndOfInfiniteScroll = false;

var ulScrollHandler = function () {
    if (hasReachedEndOfInfiniteScroll == false &&
        ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())) {
        loadMoreToInfiniteScrollUl(moreRowsUrl);
        resizeNewElements();
    }
}

function loadMoreToInfiniteScrollUl(loadMoreRowsUrl) {
    if (page > -1 && !inCallback) {
        inCallback = true;
        page++;
        $(".loading").show();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: loadMoreRowsUrl,
            data: "pageNum=" + page,
            success: function (data, textstatus) {
                if (data != '') {
                    $(".infinite-scroll").append(data);
                }
                else {
                    page = -1;
                }

                inCallback = false;
                $(".loading").hide();
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            }
        });
    }
}

function showNoMoreRecords() {
    hasReachedEndOfInfiniteScroll = true;
}
```

And this is the function that calls the infinite scroll:

```
    $(function () {
        $(".loading").hide();
    });
    var moreRowsUrl = '@Url.Action("index", "home")';
    $(window).scroll(ulScrollHandler);
```

I did some research but couldn't stabilish a reason why my code doesn't work, tried some things but did not have success. If anyone could help me, would be great! Thanks in advance, and sorry for any mistake, I'm extremely new with jQuery and Ajax.

Comment: Care to add a jsfiddle?

Comment: Did you check errors ?

Comment: What elements are you adding dynamically with the AJAX? If you're adding more `photoset` DIVs, they won't have any of the data and CSS that the `$(".photoset").each()` loop added, because that only applies to the elements that were there when the page was loaded.

Comment: maybe wrap the photoset code in a function and call it again after the dynamic content loads

Comment: That is because the `photoset()` method is not applied to newly loaded photosets—they are not available at runtime, and only added after the script is done iterating through all available photosets on DOM ready. Therefore, a solution would be to repeat the `$(".photoset").each()` on dynamically-loaded content.

Comment: @Aziz i tried this, it worked for the CSS part, but the clicking didnt work.

Comment: @Terry do you have ant suggestion on how to do that? In the same ajax code function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the *event delegation* for the click event on `.prev` and `.next` elements:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.prev', function(){.....});
    $(document).on('click', '.next', function(){.....});
});
```

Comment: And i put this code inside the "$(document).ready(function()}" part?

Comment: Yes. It will replace _click handlers_ you have declared